# distance calculation with haversine and float... kinda working

Tags: php, floating-point, distance, haversine

I'm using a haversine query to pull locations nearest to a lat/lon provided from a mobile app.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT *,(((acos(sin(($latitude *pi()/180)) * sin((`lat`*pi()/180))+cos(($latitude *pi()/180)) * cos((`lat`*pi()/180))* cos((($longitude - `lon`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) AS dist_x 
FROM `work_places`
HAVING dist_x <= '1'
ORDER BY dist_x ASC
LIMIT 10
```

This is working just fine and I'm getting exactly the locations I should be getting.

The problem is in converting dist_x to something readable by the users.  Right now, lets say dist_x reads as: 0.00996273036944 (floatval and as a string shows the same so it's converting properly)

Since the query is searching withing 1 mile, I am trying to convert this to feet so I'm dividing dist_x by 5280.

```
       $distance = (float)( $dist_x / 5280 );
```

What I get back is $distance = 1.88688075179E-6

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The conversion factor is slightly incorrect: 1852 m (nautical mile) / 1609.344 m (standard mile) ~ 1,1508. Just a minor point....

Comment: I don't understand where you're seeing those values...

Comment: At the end of the SELECT statement you have "pi())*60*1.1515". You are getting the result as radians, convert it into degrees, then into arcminutes by multiplying with 60. One arcminute is a nautical mile and a nautical mile is 1,1508 standard miles.

Comment: BTW, thanks for that... I changed the calculations from *5280 to *6076.12 which is far more accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be missing something, but if you want to convert miles to feet, don't you want to multiply by 5280 instead of dividing?

Comment: That's what happens when you work tooo many hours... you zig when you should be zagging and make stupid little mistakes and you can't figure out why you're getting the errors you're getting and you post stupid questions for other people to answer! LOL  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A mile is 5280 feet, so it should be

```
$distance = (float)( $dist_x * 5280 );
```

Comment: I gave localhost the solve because... he answered it first... but thanks!